# How to I layer area and text charts like this with Vegalite?

Tags: python, vega-lite, altair

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to layer two charts together here, so an area chart, and a text chart both appear together with vega lite.

I'm working with altair, which in turn is generating the vega specs being rendered.

Vega specs can be quite verbose, so the full dataset and generated vega spec is listed in this gist.

https://gist.github.com/mrchrisadams/67debffb4ef163e5e41c14ec634dc0fc

I'll outline the main issue I think I'm looking for help with below though.

So as I understand it, I can create an a chart from a dataset with altair/vega, and then , and then describe the mark, by encoding various kinds of info in a channel.

So for an area chart, I can do this:

```
area_chart=alt.Chart(band_df, width=600, height=400).mark_area().encode(
    alt.X('total_no:Q', stack='center', title='Number of transactions in each band'),
    alt.Y('bands:N', title='Spend bands', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(
            field="avg_value",
            op="sum", 
            order="descending" )),
    alt.Color('year(date):O', scale=alt.Scale(
            range=[ '#6CC6BC', '#49B4DF','#36508B', '#000033'])),
    alt.Column('year(date):O', title='Date')
)
```

Then later, I can do the same with another chart, but using a text mark instead of an area one:

```
text_chart = bars.mark_text(
    baseline='middle',
    dx=3  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
).encode(
    text='total_no:Q'
)
```

I can generate one at a time, and they look ok, but's not clear to me how I'd go about layering them into the same visual, as the error I get back here, isn't all that intelligible to me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SchemaValidationError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.virtualenvs/my-project-UP1n69pC/lib/python3.6/site-packages/altair/vegalite/v2/api.py in to_dict(self, *args, **kwargs)

    419         if dct is None:
    420             kwargs['validate'] = 'deep'
--> 421             dct = super(TopLevelMixin, copy).to_dict(*args, **kwargs)
    422 
    423         # TODO: following entries are added after validation. Should they be validated?

~/.virtualenvs/my-project-UP1n69pC/lib/python3.6/site-packages/altair/utils/schemapi.py in to_dict(self, validate, ignore, context)

    252                 self.validate(result)
    253             except jsonschema.ValidationError as err:
--> 254                 raise SchemaValidationError(self, err)
    255         return result
    256 

SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification

        altair.vegalite.v2.api.LayerChart->layer->items, validating 'anyOf'

{'data': {'name': 'data-8f569c8f407b14d634bf02141db458f8'}, 'mark': 'area', 'encoding': {'color': {'type': 'ordinal', 'field': 'date', 'scale': {'range': ['#6CC6BC', '#49B4DF', '#36508B', '#000033']}, 'timeUnit': 'year'}, 'column': {'type': 'ordinal', 'field': 'date', 'timeUnit': 'year', 'title': 'Date'}, 'x': {'type': 'quantitative', 'field': 'total_no', 'stack': 'center', 'title': 'Number of transactions in each band'}, 'y': {'type': 'nominal', 'field': 'bands', 'sort': {'op': 'sum', 'field': 'avg_value', 'order': 'descending'}, 'title': 'Spend bands'}}, 'height': 400, 'width': 600} is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

What do I need to do combine them?

You can post the vegaspec listed in the gists to this renderer to see what I'm going for:

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/custom/vega-lite

Bu right now, I think I stumped.

I'd be *very* grateful to get some pointers on how to combine the two charts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot layer faceted charts (in general, there is no guarantee that the facets will align). What you need to do is facet the layered chart.

I'm unable to test the code without a dataset, but it might look something like this:

```
area_chart = alt.Chart(width=600, height=400).mark_area().encode(
    alt.X('total_no:Q', stack='center', title='Number of transactions in each band'),
    alt.Y('bands:N', title='Spend bands', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(
            field="avg_value",
            op="sum", 
            order="descending" )),
    alt.Color('year(date):O', scale=alt.Scale(
            range=[ '#6CC6BC', '#49B4DF','#36508B', '#000033'])),
)

text_chart = area_chart.mark_text(
    baseline='middle',
    dx=3  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
).encode(
    text='total_no:Q'
)

alt.layer(
    area_chart,
    text_chart
).facet(
    column=alt.Column('year(date):O', title='Date'),
    data=band_df
)
```